# Selective enable/disable form fields depending on selection of other fields

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to do something similar to this:

```
            |     Column 01    |     Column 02    |    Column 03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Row 01  | ( ) Option 01_01 | ( ) Option 01_02 | ( ) Option 01_03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Row 02  | ( ) Option 02_01 | ( ) Option 02_02 | ( ) Option 02_03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Row 03  | ( ) Option 03_01 | ( ) Option 03_02 | ( ) Option 03_03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Row 04  | ( ) Option 04_01 | ( ) Option 04_02 | ( ) Option 04_03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is a subscription form where the user should select 3 of the available **Options**, but only one from each **Row** and only one from each **Column**. For example, if the user select **Option 01_02**, all other options from **Row 01** should not be available and also all the options from **Column 02** should be disabled too. Any ideas how to achieve this? I see many people using jQuery to enable/disable fields in a form, but did not find something similar of what I want to do.
Some more information that may help: the **Rows** are created based on data retrieved from a MySQL database and were implemented using radio buttons. The **Column** restriction was added later.
Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
I realized now that my example is wrong. It should be a 3x3 matrix, like this:

```
            |     Column 01    |     Column 02    |    Column 03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Row 01  | ( ) Option 01_01 | ( ) Option 01_02 | ( ) Option 01_03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Row 02  | ( ) Option 02_01 | ( ) Option 02_02 | ( ) Option 02_03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Row 03  | ( ) Option 03_01 | ( ) Option 03_02 | ( ) Option 03_03
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyway, the rules still apply:

- The user must select only one **Option** from each **Column**
- The user must select only one **Option** from each **Row**
- The user must select 3 **Options** in total.

A valid choice is: **Option 01_02**, **Option 02_01** and **Option 03_03**. The user can change his selection freely before submitting the form, but the rules must be followed. When the user changes his selection, the conflicting **Option** should be unselected and the invalid ones disabled.
My initial idea was to use radio buttons for the **Options** because of its exclusion functionality, but maybe using checkboxes provides a better solution.

Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: In your example it's impossible to selection one option from each row and column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine just finished helping me with this problem and our solution is here
http://jsfiddle.net/2zHA9/

Thanks you guys =)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a JSFiddle for what you're looking for. It's pretty crude, but hopefully this will get you up and running with what you need to do. Also, if you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

http://jsfiddle.net/g27nh/2/

Edit: I've updated it so that you can add as many rows or columns you want and it will still properly calculate them. Here's the update: http://jsfiddle.net/g27nh/4/

Comment: Hi Ben,
Thanks for your help, but I'm still having problems. I'm unable to select more than one column. I've edited my question to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this article [Radio Buttons with 2-Way Exclusivity](http://css-tricks.com/radio-buttons-with-2-way-exclusivity/)

It has an example of exactly what you are looking for.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Twix</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Snickers</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Butterfingers</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
th:empty {
    border: 0;
}
```

**jquery**

```
var col, el;

$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
   el = $(this);
   col = el.data("col");
   $("input[data-col=" + col + "]").prop("checked", false);
   el.prop("checked", true);
});
```